# Сортировка и фильтрация по полю структуры в Си

Tags: c

Есть следующие структуры:

```
typedef struct car
{
    char* model;
    char* manufacturer;
    int price;
    float consumption;
    char* modification;
} car_t;

typedef struct CarList
{
    int NumberOfCars;
    car_t* c_array;
} CarList_t;
```

я создаю экземпляр CarList и заполняю c_array экземплярами car_t. Как можно отсортировать элементы в c_array по любому полю car_t (поле выбирает пользователь)?

Comment: С помощью `qsort` и соответственно написанной функции-компаратора...

Comment: а какие я должен передавать аргументы qsort() и как примерно должна выглядеть функция компаратор?

Comment: создаёте функции сравнения `int CarCompModel(void const*,void const*)` , `int CarCompManufact(void const*,void const*)`, .. возвращающие -1 или 0 или +1. И потом уже вызываете `qsort` с аргументом нужной функции

Answer (score 0):

создаёте функции сравнения `int CarCompModel(void const*,void const*)` , `int CarCompManufact(void const*,void const*)`, .. возвращающие < 0 или == 0 или > 0. И потом уже вызываете `qsort` с аргументом нужной функции

примерно так :

```
int CarCompPrice ( void const * a , void const * b ) {
  car_t const * ca = a ;
  car_t const * cb = b ;
  return ca -> price - cb -> price ; }

# include <stdlib.h> // qsort

...

CarList_t array ;
qsort ( array . c_array , array . NumberOfCars ,
  sizeof ( car_t ) , & CarCompPrice ) ;
```

Так как функция сравнения должна возвращать целое число, просто вычитание дробных чисел не подойдёт. Так как разница 0.3 например будет преобразована на целочисленный тип int. И она станет нулю, то-есть типа числа равны, а это неправильно. Тогда это сравнение нужно делать вручную и возвращать -1 , 0 или +1

```
int CarCompConsumption ( void const * a , void const * b ) {
  car_t const * ca = a ;
  car_t const * cb = b ;
  if ( a -> consumption == b -> consumption )
    return 0 ;
  if ( a -> consumption < b -> consumption )
    return -1 ;
  return 1 ; }
```

Comment: сортировка по ценам сработала, а вот если вместо price попробовать отсортировать по model, то сортируется неправильно

Comment: у каждого поля своя сортировка и даже несколько. от меньшего к большим или наоборот. ваша попытка скорее всего была сравнением указателей, а надо было использовать сравнивать с содержимым строк. почитайте как сравнивать строки с помощью **strcmp**

Comment: а для float сортировка из ответа подойдёт?

Comment: проверил - для float не подходит, как тогда можно переписать компаратор?